# Capture Traffic amount for specific source IP for re-use

Tags: networking, traffic, capture

What is most efficient way to capture total traffic inbound/outbound amount of source IP? I want to save data about total inbound and outbound traffic amount instead of viewing live data flow that disappears after exiting the live view. I have assigned static IP's for my devices and I want to monitor the data amount like that I log them somewhere in order to make them usable with my applications or web-apps.

```
11.11.11.11 - D:30MB/U:130MB
22.22.22.22 - D:40MB/U:5MB
```

I feel that it's not very efficient if I log all the data which will be huge and sum them with my app by parsing. I think it consumes a lot of CPU when having a big history, but if there's some kind of command set I can use to write specific IP's inbound and outbound amount to file, that would be pretty good I think.

Comment: Wireshark for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `tcpdump` like:

`tcpdump -i iface# -w traffic_dump.raw host 11.11.11.11 or host 22.22.22.22` 
where `iface#` is corresponding interface on which you want to sniff the traffic - if you don't want to provide it, then just skip `-i iface#` in parameters.

After that, you can analyze offline your `taffic_dump.raw` file on various software, like `tcpdump -r` or `wireshark`, etc.